# Continuous $(x,y) \to k(x,y)$ with "discontinous slope-behavior" at one $x\to k(x,y)$-slice: Is this possible?

Tags: derivatives, continuity, slope

My question is if it is possible to construct a continuous function $k\colon[a,b]\times [c,d] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for each $v\in (c,d]$ the function $k(\cdot,v)$ its slope (i.e. derivative) is everywhere defined and finite but for $v=c$ its slope is also everywhere defined but at some point infinite ?

Somehow this seems surprisingly nontrivial to disprove, unless I overlooked something obvious.

Comment: Is $k(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{x+y}$ good for you?

Comment: Won't work. Assuming you define this on, say, $[0,1]\times [\varepsilon,1]$ for some small $\varepsilon >0$ then the slope is everywhere finite. If you define it on  $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ then $k$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$ anymore (actually, its not even defined there, but also can't be continuously extended to that point). Please check your suggestions carefully, finding such an example does not seem to be that trivial.

Comment: $k(x,y)=\sqrt{x+y}$?

Comment: If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $k:[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $k(x,y)=\sqrt{x+y}$ satisfies your conditions.